# How to set recyclerview last item to the bottom of navigation drawer in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, navigation-drawer

i am using recyclerview for navigation drawer. i need to place the last item to align bottom of the navigation drawer. How can i accomplish that. I have tried that by using offset in item decoration. It work fine with my phone, but i have used hard coded values for offset. How can i do that dynamically. Please help me with this.
 Here is the code for item decoration

```
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {

        int itemPosition = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);

        if(itemPosition == 2){
            int height = parent.getMeasuredHeight();
            int viewHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();
            outRect.top = parent.getHeight()/2 + 230;
            view.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawer_border_top));
        }

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = (new LinearLayoutManager(context);
llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
llm.setReverseLayout(true);
recList.setLayoutManager(llm);
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you know how to set last item on te bottom only if list size does not fit into the space